# how can i use the function isClicked() to fill the database?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

```
public function addAction(){

  $em = $this -> getDoctrine() -> getEntityManager();
  $a = new Button;
  $form = $this -> createForm(new ButtonType());

  $request = $this->get('request');
  $value=0;
  if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $value = $form->get('addButton')->isClicked();
    echo $value;
    if($value =1){
      $a ->setTextBox(1)
     ->setPlainText(1)
     ->setCheckBox(1)
     ->setRadio(1)
     ->setButton(1);
      $em ->persist($a);
        $em ->flush();
    }
  }    

  return $this->render('PagePageBundle:Default:add.html.twig', array( 'form' => $form -> createView(),));
}
```

I want to fill the database by clicking on a button created in the form (need help)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the method isClicked return a boolean value as described in the [doc](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/Form/ClickableInterface.html#isClicked()) so you can simply check this (in your code you write a wrong if statement: = instead of ==)

So try this code:

```
$value = $form->get('addButton')->isClicked();
    var_dump($value);
    if($value){
        $a ->setTextBox(1)
           ->setPlainText(1)
           ->setCheckBox(1)
           ->setRadio(1)
           ->setButton(1);
        $em ->persist($a);
        $em ->flush();
  }
```

hope this help

Comment: thank you ! But i still have one problem when i refresh the page value still true so the database fill automatically

Comment: yes, if you refresh and confirm the submitting of the page is normally, if you don't want this behaviour I suggest you to redirect to another page if the submit is correctly submitted.